# wordpress hook & filter invocation

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress plugin.php has an internal function

```
function _wp_call_all_hook($args) {
 global $wp_filter;

 reset( $wp_filter['all'] );
 do {
    foreach( (array) current($wp_filter['all']) as $the_ )
        if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
            call_user_func_array($the_['function'], $args);

 } while ( next($wp_filter['all']) !== false );
}
```

I fail to understand the need to write the code in the manner written above. What is a possible problem if it had been written more simply like

```
function _wp_call_all_hook($args) {
 global $wp_filter;

 foreach($wp_filter['all'] as $the_ )
    if ( !is_null($the_['function']) )
        call_user_func_array($the_['function'], $args);
 }
}
```